# Passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

i'm not sure what's going on. New to C and trying to make a simple program that just checks if two strings are equal. (It's supposed to be a simple Hash Validator)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char hash1, hash2;
    char result;
    // read hashes as strings
    printf("Insert first hash\\n");
    scanf("%s", &hash1);
    printf("Insert second hash\\n");
    scanf("%s", &hash2);

    result = strcmp(hash1, hash2);
    
    if (result == "0") {
        printf("VALID MATCH");

    }   else {
        printf("INVALID MATCH");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the two error messages I get when the code stops at the strcmp line:
"message": "passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"
"message": "passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"

Thanks in advance

Didn't know what to try honestly. I tried doing some research but users have an issue with mixing up integers and stirngs resulting in the same error. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: `strcmp()` expects two `char *` values; you are passing two `char` values.  Although adding `&` before each argument would pass `char *` values, you have to work harder because `strcmp()` expects that its arguments point to null-terminated strings, and your single `char` variables are not null-terminated strings.

Comment: `char` means a single character. I guess you want to have multiple characters .

Comment: `hash1` and `hash2` should be strings and not single characters, e.g. `char hash1[50];` and `result` should be of type `int`.

Comment: If you're new to C, you need to reread the section of your textbook or tutorial on characters and strings, because you didn't get it the first time.

Comment: This program has 100% undefined behavior. The longest "string" that can be stored in these variables is an empty string. Anything longer will cause `scanf` to write past the end of these objects into other memory. And the degenerate case where the user terminates the input without entering anything will result in passing pointers to uninitialized memoy into `strcmp` which is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @shuichisaito, Please post sample input.

Comment: I wrote a little beginner FAQ about string handling here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). Check out the first two entries in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash1` and `hash2` are single `char` variables, which get promoted to `int` when passed to functions.  You should defined these as `char` arrays.

Also correct some other issues:

- `main()` is incorrect: `main` without arguments should have a prototype `int main(void)`
- pass `scanf` the maximum number of characters to store into the destination `char` arrays not counting the null terminator.
- test the return value of `scanf()`.
- `result` should have type `int` and if it is non zero, only the sign of its value matters.
- `if (result == "0")` is incorrect: you should write `if (result == 0)`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char hash1[100], hash2[100];
    int result;

    // read hashes as strings
    printf("Insert first hash\\n");
    if (scanf("%99s", hash1) != 1) {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Insert second hash\\n");
    if (scanf("%99s", hash2) != 1) {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    result = strcmp(hash1, hash2);

    if (result == 0) {
        printf("VALID MATCH\n");
    } else {
        printf("INVALID MATCH\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```